# How do I retrieve latest record in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a table called `Students`.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

id     name          course             date_admitted
1      Pankesh        EEE            2020-10-21 07:52:30.977
2      Pankesh        IT             2020-11-03 11:53:20.976
3      Pankesh        CE             2020-09-11 08:30:29.975

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I want to retrieve is the latest record

```
2      Pankesh        IT            2020-11-03 11:53:20.976
```

What is the `SQL` Query Statement for this instance?

Comment: Simple way: ORDER BY, SELECT TOP 1

Comment: if you have groups use a window function inside a CTE `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(name order by date_admitted DESC) AS SEQ` then select from cte where `seq = 1`

Comment: select top(1) *  from Students order by date_admitted desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just one row, you can `order by` and `fetch`:

```
select s.*
from students s
order by date_admitted desc
offset 0 rows fetch first 1 row only
```

Or using `top()`:

```
select top (1) s.*
from students s
order by date_admitted desc
```

On the other hand, if you want the latest row *per student*, then it is a top 1 per group problem. You can use window functions:

```
select s.*
from (
    select s.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by name order by date_admitted desc) rn
    from students s
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I've edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @TechGeek49: this appears to do what you ask for. Are you having a specific problem with the queries I provided?

Comment: Not really coz I wanna retrieve the latest data without considering the position of it

Comment: Thanks buddy. Could you mind upvoting this question albeit it's being listed as duplicate?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look